# Как подключить к Html внешний Html

Tags: javascript

Есть страница 1 (новостная) со списком коротких новостей, но со ссылкой на другую страницу 2 Html, на полную новость. Как автоматизировать страницу 1 так, что бы она автоматически загружала часть текста со страницы 2 (только текст, а не какое-то окно на соседнюю страницу)? Например, на странице 1 пишу скрипт, который ищет id="..."с страницы 2, и подставляет в id="..." страницы 1. Ищу в интернете а там кругом только как подключать внешний CSS или Javascript

Comment: про `ajax` почитайте

Answer (score 1):

Можно JS-аяксом подгрузить определенный элемент по id.

```
$("#id1").load("/page2.html #id2");
```

Данный код вытащит содержимое из `id2` на странице `page2.html` и расположит в `id1` на странице, в которую вы впишете данный скрипт. Подразумевается, что у вас подключен `jQuery`

Comment: Впервые вижу такой финт с id в load. Что впрочем неудивительно, ибо грузить целую страницу ради одного элемента - это несколько нелогично.

Comment: @Qwertiy не видел другого способа получить содержимое элемента на странице. Всё равно приходится грузить всю страницу целиком.